# Eloquent Relations - Dealing with Unnecessary Conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

When I retrieve data directly from the model using the following approach:

```
Contact::where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)->get()
```

The query looks like this:

```
select * from "contacts" where "company_id" = 'xxx'
```

But when I retrieve data through direct relations like this:

```
auth()->user()->company->contacts
```

The query looks like this and takes longer:

```
select * from "contacts" where "contacts"."company_id" = 'xxx' and "contacts"."company_id" is not null
```

It adds the additional;

```
and "contacts"."company_id" is not null
```

part, which affects performance negatively. What should I do to prevent this? Querying directly from models without using relations anywhere also doesn't seem very logical and clean.

Note: company_id is indexed.

Comment: If you excluded that clause `... is not null` then when your user has `company_id = null` the query will match all the `contacts` with `company_id = null`. I do not think this is the result that you want. Correct? Is the `company_id` not nullable in both tables?

Comment: no, not nullable. but i understand the cause of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$company = new Company;
```

The Company model hasn't been saved yet, so there is no primary key yet, it exists only as a PHP object, but since relationships will generate and execute SQL, the $contacts variable below will be filled with values where company_id is null. To prevent this,
IS NOT NULL has been added to the query.

```
$contacts = $company->contacts;
```

[source](https://laravel.gen.tr/d/8457-relationship-query-farkliligi/6)